# Svg in pug syntax

Tags: svg, pug

I'm trying to show a svg icon on html page with pug syntax, but doesn't work

This is the code

```
span.icon
  svg(width="24px", height="24px")
    use(xlink:href="../../../images/svg/glass.svg")
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<use>` element cannot link to complete files, only to named fragments. [There is a proposal](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseElement) to change this in the future, but for now, the root `<svg>` element in file `glass.svg` needs to have an id, lets say `id="glassRoot"`. Then you can do

```
span.icon
  svg(width="24px", height="24px")
    use(xlink:href="../../../images/svg/glass.svg#glassRoot")
```

Answer (score -2):

Add id="glassRoot" -> (#glassRoot) after glass.svg.

Comment: Please include the solution in the body of your answer. Answers are meant to help others in the future, and links can go dead. See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info